# if statement inside a react tooltip

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm a student. We have a class where we work on projects that previous students have worked on throughout a few years, try to improve them, add new things real customers want. I feel I've been thrown in the deep end with this one.

I've never used react or Django, so its a steep learning curve, but this is a web app that displays information from heat sensors around our building.

My task sounds very basic: display two separate tool-tip bubbles one showing heat and temperate, the other showing co2.

```
render() {
  const sensors = this.props.sensors.filter(
    sensor => sensor.floor === this.props.floor
  );
  if (this.props.loading) {
    return (
      <ReactLoading
        className="busy wrapper"
        type="spinningBubbles"
        color="grey"
        height={100}
        width={100}
      />
    );
  }
  return [
    <div id="sensors" key="sensors" className={this.props.floor.toString()}>
      {sensors.map((sensor, index) => (
        <ReactTooltip
          key={index}
          id={sensor.serialID.toString()}
          type="info"
          effect="solid"
        >
          <span className="reading">ID: {sensor.serialID}</span>
          <span className="reading">Name: {sensor.name}</span>
          //conditional statement to seperate the two
          {sensor.temperature !== null && (
            <span className="reading">Temperature: {sensor.temperature}</span>
          )}
          {sensor.humidity !== null && (
            <span className="reading">Humidity: {sensor.humidity}</span>
          )}
          <span className="reading">C02:{sensor.co2}</span>
        </ReactTooltip>
      ))}
    </div>
  ];
}
```

this bit of code I was told needed an if statement so two circles would show up currently their is only one

[image: example image]

I've looked around but because I actually don't know what I'm doing I was hoping someone here may be able to help/explain

Comment: 1. Why are you returning an array rather than an object? 2. Your are currently returning the whole information as one tooltip. If your intention is to show the tooltip when the user hovers the ball, then you could use the css before and after property and determine visibility with class addition/removal on hover.  Or You could render the tooltip position as absolute with the ball as relative.

Comment: @Tolumide it *is* valid JSX syntax, albeit, not a very common convention. OP said this is an old, on-going codebase for students, so it likely was coded that way previously by someone else and is really outside the scope of the question/issue posed.

Comment: Alright, Thank you for that. Have you gotten a solution yet?
Is the code above yours?
Have you tried the approach I suggested

Answer (score 0):

The common pattern for conditionally rendering JSX in react is with a ternary.

```
{someCondition ? (/* JSX if true */) : (/* JSX if false */)
```

In your code you could toggle the tooltip contents on some toggleable value somewhere in the UI. For example, here I've assume some variable `displayTempHumidity` exists.

```
{sensors.map((sensor, index) => (
  <ReactTooltip
    key={index}
    id={sensor.serialID.toString()}
    type="info"
    effect="solid"
  >
    <span className="reading">ID: {sensor.serialID}</span>
    <span className="reading">Name: {sensor.name}</span>

    //conditional statement to seperate the two
    {displayTempHumidity ? (
      <Fragment>
        {sensor.temperature !== null && (
          <span className="reading">Temperature: {sensor.temperature}</span>
        )}
        {sensor.humidity !== null && (
          <span className="reading">Humidity: {sensor.humidity}</span>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    ) : (
      <span className="reading">C02:{sensor.co2}</span>
    )}
  </ReactTooltip>
))}
```

Let me know if the `Fragment` makes sense where I've used it.

Just out of curiosity, do you know what version of React your project is running? If it is an older codebase and packages haven't been updated then the landscape may be a little different than current practices.

Answer (score 0):

For IF condition inside  you can use below format

```
<ReactTooltip
      key={index}
      id={sensor.serialID.toString()}
      type="info"
      effect="solid"
    >
{xyz == 123 && <span>Heat and temp</span> //xyz == 123 will be your condition which you want to put in IF statement
{xyz == 345 && <sapn>CO2</span> //First argument before && will act like your conditional statement
</ReactTooltip>
```